# Control a SainSmart 20x4 LCD?

Tags: display, i2c

I've got some [SainSmart 20x4 LCD](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B007XRHBKA/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1638&creative=19454&creativeASIN=B007XRHBKA&linkCode=as2&tag=schoebprode-21) left over from my Arduino projects and I wanted to check if and how it's possible to get them running with an Raspberry Pi. I've come across [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7981/connecting-to-an-lcd-via-i2c).

Unfortunately, my distributor only provides an Arduino library. What's a practical way to get it running with an Raspberry over I2C? Is there a way to control it in a C application?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking more toward Python. Here is a link to the packages that you will need to install on the RasPi.
[Necessary Packages](http://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/necessary-packages)